# Show that exists a field isomorphism $\bar{\varphi} : K[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle \to E[x]/\langle p*(x) \rangle $

Tags: galois-theory

Let $\varphi:K \to E $ a field isomorphism and $p(x)\in K[x]$ irreducible. Show that exists a field isomorphism $\bar{\varphi} : K[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle \to E[x]/\langle p*(x) \rangle $

if $p(x)=a_0 + a_1x + \dots+ a_nx^n$
then $p*(x)=\varphi (a_0) + \varphi(a_1) x + \dots+ \varphi(a_n)x^n$

so i think i can do $\bar{\varphi}(g(x)+ \langle p(x))=g(x)+\langle p*(x)\rangle $ but i dont know im stuck